# Force WordPress to ignore the w url parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

Say, I have a WordPress installation running at example.com and have the following url

http://example.com/blah?w=100

Now, I want WordPress to ignore the w=100 part because, every time I pass a numeric argument to w, WordPress redirects me to the single page, I assume this has something to do with Attachments.

I can't rename w to anything else because it is out of my control, my site has to work with a third party application that will not let me alter this condition.

I tried this

```
add_filter('request', array($this,'on_request'));
function on_request($vars){
  unset($vars['w']);
  return $vars;
}
```

And it wouldn't work - any advice on this please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I solved it myself.

```
add_filter( 'request', 'alter_the_query' );
function alter_the_query( $request ) {

    unset($request['w']);
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: why is the "$dummy_query = new WP_Query();  // the query isn't run if we don't pass any query vars
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );"  needed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question - are you asking why that line is required?

Comment: yea, exactly, it doesnt seem doing anything

Comment: It is creating a new instance of WP_Query.

Comment: If you just want this be done for a subset of your website, wrap the `unset` command in an if statement - this means it can still be used by WordPress where appropriate

Answer (score 4):

I would be careful with this approach. The `w` parameter is a [WordPress reserved query variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables). The parameter is used to find the week number based on the start_of_week option in the settings and likely affects a bunch of queries.

If you are unable to change the parameter like you mentioned, I would, if possible, at least check if the request comes from that third party provider and only then unset the parameter.

Comment: I didn't know that it is reserved query variable, I assumed it had something to do with resizing images and w stood for width, since it only accepts numeric values. I will follow your instructions on this, thank you very much.

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, It is used for week.